# Are these file handling functions safe?

Tags: c, security, file

I'm using these 2 functions to handle file input/output and would like to know if there's anything that should be changed.

For content retrieval, enough space is allocated and the file content is copied. To make sure saving a file either saves all or nothing, I'm writing to a buffer then renaming it after all content is successfully written.

I'm particularly interested in knowing whether these functions are safe or not since `tmpnam` is considered dangerous. I read the main risk is a file with the name returned by `tmpnam` being created before we are able to do it, so I'm using `wbx`to make sure it doesn't happen. Is this enough or there are other security concerns that I'm not aware of?

**files.h**

```
#ifndef FILES_H
#define FILES_H

#include <stdlib.h>

#define FILE_SUCCESS 0
#define FILE_ERROR 1

void *file_get_content(const char *file_name, size_t *file_size_fill);

//Save all or nothing
int file_save_content(  const char *file_name, 
                        const void *content, 
                        size_t size             );

#endif
```

**files.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include "files.h"

#define BYTE 1
#define READ_MODE "rb"

//Use the new "x" subspecifier so fopen will fail if a file with the name
//returned by tmpnam exists
#define SAFE_WRITE "wbx"


void *file_get_content(const char *file_name, size_t *file_size_fill)
{
    //Get file size, SEEK_END is not portable
    struct stat file_stat;
    if(stat(file_name, &file_stat) != 0)
        return NULL;

    //Check if the file actually contains anything, since malloc can return
    //values other than NULL for malloc(0)
    if(file_stat.st_size == 0)
        return NULL;

    //Space to save the contents
    void *content = malloc(file_stat.st_size);
    if(content == NULL)
        return NULL;

    //Open file
    FILE *file = fopen(file_name, READ_MODE);
    if(file == NULL){
        free(content);
        return NULL;
    }

    //Read it all
    if(fread(content, BYTE, file_stat.st_size, file) != file_stat.st_size){
        free(content);
        fclose(file);
        return NULL;
    }

    fclose(file);

    *file_size_fill = file_stat.st_size;
    return content;
}

//Save the file content safely, it either saves all or nothing
int file_save_content(  const char *file_name,
                        const void *content,
                        size_t size             )
{
    //Get a name for the temp file
    char temp_file_name[L_tmpnam];
    if(tmpnam(temp_file_name) == NULL)
        return FILE_ERROR;

    //Create it
    FILE *temp_file = fopen(temp_file_name, SAFE_WRITE);
    if(temp_file == NULL)
        return FILE_ERROR;

    //Write
    if(fwrite(content, BYTE, size, temp_file) != size){
        fclose(temp_file);
        remove(temp_file_name);
        return FILE_ERROR;
    }

    //Replace old file
    fclose(temp_file);
    if(rename(temp_file_name, file_name) != 0){
        remove(temp_file_name);
        return FILE_ERROR;
    }

    return FILE_SUCCESS;
}
```

**`file_save_content()` after following the suggestions given by 200_success**

```
int file_save_content(const char *file_name, const void *content, size_t size)
{
    /* Create temp file */
    char tmp[] = {'t','m','p','X','X','X','X','X','X', '\0'};
    int error;
    int fd = mkstemp(tmp);

    if(fd == -1)
        return FILE_ERROR;

    if(write(fd, content, size) != (ssize_t)size){
        error = errno;
        close(fd);
        errno = error;
        return FILE_ERROR;
    }

    /* Replace old file */
    if(rename(tmp, file_name) != 0){
        error = errno;
        unlink(tmp);
        close(fd);
        errno = error;
        return FILE_ERROR;
    }

    close(fd);

    return FILE_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that a more idiomatic C interface would be

```
ssize_t file_get_content(const char *file_name, char *content[]);
```

Returning the number of bytes actually read would be analogous to `read(2)` and `printf(3)`.  On error, the return value could be `-1`, and the reason would be in `errno`.  For consistency, I would have `file_save_content()` return the number of bytes written, or `-1` on error.

It would be convenient if you allocated an extra byte and appended a `\0` terminator to the result.  Then the caller has the option to treat the buffer as a null-terminated string, if it believes the file to contain text.  It would still be able to treat it as binary data (possibly containing `NUL` bytes) based on the return value.

When getting the contents of an empty file, I would expect it to produce an "empty" buffer, not a `NULL` pointer.

There is a possibility of a race condition: the file could be truncated between the `stat()` and the `fread()`.  You could actually handle that case a bit more gracefully.

```
int file_get_content(const char *file_name, char *buf[]) {
    struct stat file_stat;
    if (0 != stat(file_name, &file_stat)) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (NULL == (*buf = 1 + malloc(file_stat.st_size))) {
        return -1;
    }

    FILE *file;
    if (NULL == (file = fopen(file_name, "rb"))) {
        free(*buf);
        return -1;
    }

    ssize_t bytes_read = fread(*buf, 1, file_stat.st_size, file);
    (*buf)[bytes_read] = '\0';
    fclose(file);
    return bytes_read;
}
```

---

In `file_save_content()`, avoid `tmpnam()`, which allows a race condition between the time you call `tmpnam()` and `fopen()`.  Also, `rename()` would fail unless the temporary file and the destination are on the same filesystem.  As an alternative, I would recommend `mkstemp()` with the destination filename plus a `".XXXXXX"` suffix, followed by `fdopen()`.

As a nitpick, I'd prefer `unlink()` over `remove()`, since the former refuses to remove directories.

In the error handlers of `file_save_content()`, save and restore `errno`, because it would be more useful for the caller to see the original reason for the failure rather than a problem with the subsequent cleanup.

Comment: +1, nice answer.  Note that `(*buf)[1 + bytes_read] = '\0';` should drop the 1

Comment: @WilliamMorris Thanks! Fixed in [Rev 2](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/39926/2).

Comment: Thank you for reviewing the code. Do you mind explaining how could a race condition happen when calling `fopen` with the x subspecifier since it will only be opened if the file doesn't exist?

Comment: There is a slim chance that a colliding file could be created between [`tmpnam()` and `fopen()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check-to-time-of-use). Fortunately, there is no security hole, since you call `fopen()` with the `"x"` flag, but an attacker _might_ be able to cause grief by triggering failures. It's a farfetched scenario, but an avoidable one.